# android.security.KeyChainException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: uid

Tags: android, keychain

Error:

```
android.security.KeyChainException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: uid 10111 doesn't have permission to access the requested alias
```

Code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                X509Certificate[] myCertificates=KeyChain.getCertificateChain(MainActivity.this, "ServerCertificate");
                if(myCertificates!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println("myCertificates size "+myCertificates.length);

                    for(int i=0;i<myCertificates.length;i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println("myCertificates i= "+i+"    "+myCertificates[i]);
                    }
                }
            } catch (KeyChainException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 6):

The `KeyChain` class requires the application to call `choosePrivateKeyAlias()` at least once after the application is installed before calling `getPrivateKey()` or `getCertificateChain()`. So even if one knows the alias beforehand, the `choosePrivateKeyAlias()` must be called at least once, otherwise there is no trust established between the app and the internal database that `KeyChain` uses.