# Retrieving installed certificates on Android Keychain

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, keychain

I have a x509 certificate that I installed using this code:

```
var certificate = AssetManagement.GetCertificate (xdoc); //this is a helper class that retrieves the certificate

//Code to install to keychain
Intent intent = KeyChain.CreateInstallIntent ();
intent.PutExtra (KeyChain.ExtraCertificate, certificate.GetRawCertData());
intent.PutExtra (KeyChain.ExtraName, "AzureManagement");

StartActivity (intent);
```

The code successfully calls the android UI to install a certificate and forces the user to set a PIN to protect the device. That works fine.

But when I try to access the keychain like this:

```
var chain = KeyChain.GetCertificateChain (this, "My cert alias");
```

I get the following error: `Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock`

What is the correct way to access the keychain?

Comment: Does anyone know how to achieve this using C#/Xamarin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is really great. It's telling you "please, don't do that this way : you may block the user interface". Android UI (display and user events) are handled by a thread in Android : the UI Thread a.k.a the main thread.

If you do something that may take time like a network call, or writing to a file, then you may block the UI and the app will look unresponsive to your users, and it can even stop working by provoking an ANR (App Not Responding).

So the answer is simple, do it in a different thread. On Android, [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) are meant to help you achieve this kind of things fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try setting up an async call

Comment: I correctly setup an AsyncTask for this, but now I'm getting the error described here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122160/android-security-keychainexception-java-lang-illegalstateexception-uid

What's the correct way to call ChoosePrivateKeyAlias() I can't find documentaiton anywhere

Comment: I am sending to someone that is overskilled on that matter, you should be answered soon.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same Problem as ahmed, on how to call ChoosePrivateKeyAlias() properly. How did you solved it?

Comment: Did you try with an AsyncTask ?